# How to make discord bot send images from an online link python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want my discord bod to send a image from an online link instead of using a local link when a command is used. How can i do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack! What do you mean by online link? Have you tried anything? Please view [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed explanation is in the [FAQ of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image)

```py
import io
import aiohttp

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(my_url) as resp:
        if resp.status != 200:
            return await channel.send('Could not download file...')
        data = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
        await channel.send(file=discord.File(data, 'cool_image.png'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your image to a site like Imgur and then use the link to send the image! Here's an example:

```
@bot.command()
async def image(ctx):
    await ctx.send("image_link")
```

Hope this helps!