# How to make discord.py send an image from a url?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an image from the internet that I want to a channel on a server, but I want the image to be **displayed** and not sent as a file. I also don't want to send the link itself.

Comment: I recommend you to checkout this other SO question. Maybe it could helps you. [How to make discord bot send images from an online link python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189435/how-to-make-discord-bot-send-images-from-an-online-link-python)

Comment: I did try this, but it sends the image as a file and does not show the image itself. I want the image to be displayed too.

Comment: @Space.yg, it's apparently a loading problem: https://gamertweak.com/discord-images-files/. Try using [`discord.Embed()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.image) instead.

Comment: Usually discord is smart enough to only display the actual image and nothing else when you send only the url. What are you sending right now?

Answer (score 5):

You can do upload a file from url using discord.py, io, and aiohttp. you can do so like this:

```py
import aiohttp
import discord

channel = client.get_channel(123567890000000) # replace id
url = "your image url" # must be an image
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: # creates session
    async with session.get(url) as resp: # gets image from url
        img = await resp.read() # reads image from response
        with io.BytesIO(img) as file: # converts to file-like object
            await channel.send(file=discord.File(file, "testimage.png"))
```

This is all asynchronous.
(You can replace "channel" to ctx if you're using this as command)